# The difference between 执著 and 固执

Tags: grammar

I had this sentence: 麦当劳一直执著地坚持着浓浓的美式风格。

I would translate '执著地坚持着‘ as 'stubbornly persist in'

I was told, '执着‘ has a positive sense, whereas '固执‘ has more of a negative sense of 'persisting even though you know it is wrong to do so'.

Would you agree?

Comment: dictionaries agree:
执著 
inflexible ； rigid ； punctilious
 e.g. iciba:原为佛教语，指对某一事物坚持不放。.泛指固执或拘泥，亦指对某种事物追求不舍。originally a Buddhist term, adamantly clinging to something, rigidly adhering to something, also means unrelentingly pursuing something.
固执 obstinate ； stubborn ；释义
1. （动）坚持己见；不肯改变。～己见｜性情～。（作谓语）
2. （形）坚持己见不肯改变的（性格）。这个人很～。（作谓语）persist, unwilling to change.
see example sentences in iciba, showing negative connotation.

Answer (score 2):

He/She is right. 执着 is more positive,like "persistent" or "Never give up,never surrender!"
While 固执 stands for "stubborn",you can use it to describe annoying kids who just refuse to eat carrots...something like that.
 However,sometimes (less commonly) 固执 can have positive meaning too. It really depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

McDonald's has been firmly insisted on a strong American style

Or:

with determination,

dedicated,

persistently,

Do not use 'stubbornly persist in'.

Comment: Thanks, but I would just point out that 'has been firmly insisted on' is not good English.  I would say because the past tense would be 'M. was insisted on'. Basically, you can't passivize 'insist on'.

Answer (score 0):

执着 = persistent, 固执 = stubborn. Most of the times 执着 is a good word, 固执 is a bad word.

so if you write "麦当劳一直执著地坚持着浓浓的美式风格。", you are implying they should keep their American style, so it's a compliment.

If you write "麦当劳一直固执地坚持着浓浓的美式风格。", you are implying they shouldn't keep their American style, so it's criticism.

And my translation would be "McDonald has always been persistent in keeping the American style"

Answer (score 0):

In short:

執著(执着) should focus on some thing.

固執(固执) use to describe someone's characteristic.

We would say 王先生執著於賺到一百萬元

We would NOT say 王先生固執於賺到一百萬元

in other words

We would say 王先生的個性很固執

We would NOT say 王先生的個性很執著